# Radio btn-group inside input-group-addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to put a (2 button) radio btn-group inside of an input-group-addon. The trouble I'm having there is that the buttons do not stay on one line.

The common patterns to keep elements on the same line did not work for me.

Do you know how I could fix this? Thx

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/144/

```
<div id="filter_criteria_date">
<div class="input-group" style='margin-top:15px'> <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">And</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Or</button>
    </div>
    </span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control filter_text" placeholder="Filter">
</div>
```

Comment: Set a width for the parent of the buttons? `.btn-group { width: 100px; }`is that what you mean? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/DTcHh/145/)

Comment: Sweet. That seems to do the trick. Thank you Ruddy!

Comment: Yeah, I will. It says I have to wait 7 min...

Comment: Working Demo => http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/148/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not stay on one line due to no width being set. Set a width for the parent of the buttons and they will fit.

```
.btn-group { 
    width: 100px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/DTcHh/147/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   .input-group-addon { width:auto; }
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/148/

Comment: Thanks for that answer. This is really elegant. Do you know how I could make the text input to the right of the input-group-addon to take the rest of the parent div (without the addon getting wider)?

Comment: not getting your point, as i am assume input text alignment from right side just put text box css property `text-align:right;`

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I meant this: Is it possible for the text input field to take the entire remaining width, such that the addon stays the same width? In other words: Can I achieve that the text onput covers the red area? http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/150/

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you can see in the update jsfiddle, the input-group-addon expands a bit as well. It's not too bad, I was just wondering whether it was possible to stretch the text input without changing the input-group-addon's width.